# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

[this is the code I am working with:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZEPh.png)

I searched for a similiar error do i need to change the .close() ?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: `close` is a method of an open file.  The object that you are calling close on is actually a `tensor`, not a file.  You need to review how that object was defined.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj :) managed to solve the issue it was actually a typo error! i was meant to write clone instead of close... eh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the close() function call on the parameter tensor image in line -
`image = tensor.cpu().close().detach().numpy()`. This should be replaced with - `image = tensor.cpu().detach().numpy()`

Comment: Hi Aditya :) managed to solve the issue it was actually a typo error! i was meant to write clone instead of close...  thanks!